# Running different rails webserver as per choice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

now by default whenever I run rails s it starts rails with puma

I want to able to run webrick in my development environment as puma doesn't work well when debugging with byebug

```
# Gemfile
gem 'puma'

# config/puma.rb
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)

threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)

threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup

port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000

environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by restricting the *puma* gem to production (and maybe test too if it suits your needs) environments only.

```
# Gemfile
group :test, :production do
  gem 'puma'
end
```

Then run `bundle install --without test production`.

Comment: Have you deleted your `Gemfile.lock` file and ran `bundle install`?

Comment: Can you try `bundle clean --force` and then `bundle install`?

Comment: You are correct. It looks like you cannot do it without that switch.